# How to modifying a source file "file.cs" using an custom auto-generation tool during build process?

Tags: c#, build, build-process

I am creating `ResourceDictionarya` and i want to create an `enum` that contain all the target `ResourceDictionary` Keys, to use in my code, to reduce the typing errors i tried to make a simpe `tool.exe` and called it in the `Pre-build` Action, but i am looking for best way to do that, any one help me please.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) to get the job done.  A T4 template can generate a C# file and you can configure [your build](http://www.olegsych.com/2010/04/understanding-t4-msbuild-integration/#ConfiguringProject) to regenerate the file every time.